# Is there any SP app that i can use for an examination environment?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, apple-ios

I have a project that is trying to implement on the SharePoint online environment. 
Would like to find out if there's an open source examination application or code for the trainer and the candidate to use. 
Another requirement is that it has to be running on an iPad, to be portable for the candidate to do their examinations.

Thank you! 
  -xxmfxx

Answer (score 0):

Since you have access to SharePoint online I guess you also have access to Forms which can run a quiz, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-quiz-with-microsoft-forms-a082a018-24a1-48c1-b176-4b3616cdc83d
Is that a option?

Comment: Hi! Hmm~ Or is there any other application(s) that can also function a screen lockdown ? Been trying to find for an application/software that does a screen lockdown